# Diagonalizabilty of a restriction implies diagonalizability of original operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, quotient-spaces, minimal-polynomials

I'm stuck trying to solve this problem.

V is finite dimensional vector space over the complex numbers. Suppose $L: V \longrightarrow V$ is linear, and furthermore suppose$U \subset V$ subspace such that $U \subset \ker(L)$ and $im(L)\cap U=\{0\}$. Show that if the induced linear map $L': V/U \longrightarrow V/U $ is diagonalizable, then L is diagonalizable.

First I have tried to consider $L'$ and its basis consisting of eigenvectors such that it is diagonal, also it's minimal polynomial $f(t)=(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_k)$. Then I can write $L$ in this basis as a block matrix where
L in the given basis is

\begin{bmatrix}
    L' & B &  \\
   0 & C &  \\
\end{bmatrix}
Still, I am not sure how to proceed. Do I need to show that $U$ is invariant under $L$? Thank you

This is not the same as the problem where you are given a diagonal operator and trying to show that its restriction is diagonal.

Comment: It is not a duplicate! Here we are going backwards. We have that a restriction is diagonalizable and we are trying to get that the original operator is diagonalizable.

Comment: My bad! Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L'$ is diagonalizable then its minimal polynomial $P(t)$ is a product of distinct linear factors, and for all $v\in V$ we have $(P(L))(v)\in U$. Distinguish two cases:

1. If $P(0)\neq0$ then $tP(t)$ is a product of distinct linear factors, and $L(P(L))(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$ because $(P(L))(v)\in U\subset\ker L$, so the minimal polynomial of $L$ divides $tP(t)$.
2. If $P(0)=0$ then $(P(L))(v)\in\operatorname{im}(L)$ for all $v\in V$. From $\operatorname{im}(L)\cap U=0$ it follows that $P(L)=0$, so the minimal polynomial of $L$ divides $P(t)$.

Comment: Thank you! I am bit tired, will try to read more carefully tomorrow. But it makes sense to me.

Comment: I had one question -- in the first paragraph of your argument you say that $(P(L))(v)=0$ for all v? Why is it the  case ? Why L also satisfies the minimal polynomial for L'?

Comment: Is it because U is in the kernel ?

Comment: Also in the first case you assume that minimal polynomial of L divides $tP(t)$ , but why does it guarantee digonalizability?

Comment: I first claim that $(P(L))(v)\in U$ for all $v\in V$. This is true because $(P(L'))(v')=0$ for all $v'\in V/U$. Then it follows that $L(P(L))(v)=0$ because $U\subset\ker L$. This shows that the minimal polynomial of $L$ divides $tP(t)$, which is a product of distinct linear factors because $P(0)\neq0$.

Comment: Oh I see, very dumb of me. Thank you so much for all your help!!!!

Comment: This is correct +1. Just some minor suggestions: (1) rather than $P(0)=0$ I would have said "$t$ divides $P$", which is how this is used; (2) the case distinction can be avoided by taking the least common multiple of $t$ and $P$, which is a split square-free annihilator of $L$ in all cases; (3) in the second case you could have said that the minimal polynomial of $L$ _is_ $P$ (in the first case it is also $tP$, unless $\dim U=0$).

Answer (score 1):

This is immediate once you reformulate the question a bit. Since $U$ intersects the image of $L$ trivially, one can extend that image to a subspace$~W$ complementary to$~U$. Then choosing some basis according to the decomposition $V=U\oplus W$, the matrix of $L$ with respect to this basis has the block form
$$
M=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&D},
$$
since $L(U)=0$ and $L(W)\subseteq W$. The quotient map $V\to V/U$ restricted to$~W$ gives an isomorphism $W\to V/U$, and taking the image of the basis of $W$ as basis of $V/U$, the matrix of $L'$ on this basis is$~D$.

So we are given that $D$ is diagonalisable and asked to prove that $M$ is diagonalisable, which is pretty obvious (a block diagonal matrix built from diagonalisable blocks, here $0$ and $D$, is diagonalisable).